# linkedin sharing is giving me a content security policy when using react-share

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api, content-security-policy, react-share

I am getting an error that shows the error below when using an NPM package react-share.
Refused to load manifest from 'https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/8ekldmhv4d8prk5sml735t6np' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "manifest-src 'self'".

I've also tried to hardcode the URL into the share link
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fq.sparksandhoney.com%2Freport%2F622bc4fc659871873884fdaa&mini=true